# Converting text graphics to SVG results in corrupted rendering

Tags: c#, .net, svg, graphics

I need to convert GraphicsPath to SVG. I used the following piece of code:

```
SvgDocument d = new SvgDocument();
SvgPath p = new SvgPath();

var a = DrawText(tBText.Text);
string b = "M";
foreach (var item in a.PathPoints)
{
    b += " " + item.ToSvgString();
}
    
p.PathData = SvgPathBuilder.Parse(b);
d.Children.Add(p);
pictureBox1.Image = d.Draw();
d.Write("ss.svg");
```

DrawText function is here:

```
private GraphicsPath DrawText(string text)
        {
            Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
            Font font = new Font("Jameel Noori Nastaleeq", 24, FontStyle.Regular);
            GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
            using (StringFormat sf = new StringFormat())
            {
                sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

                gp.FillMode = FillMode.Winding;
                
                gp.AddString(text, font.FontFamily, (int)font.Style, font.Size, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle, sf);
                gp.ClearMarkers();
                g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
                g.DrawPath(Pens.Red, gp);

            }
            return gp;
        }
```

The issue is that it is not converting to SVG properly and the rendering looks corrupted. For example, the word "Hello" looks like this:

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: There is no BCL way to do this, However, you will likely find libraries to help you

Comment: Interesting. I would expect you'd need to look into the [PathTypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.pathtypes?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) as well , though

Comment: You should tag the library you use!

Comment: Pathtype = 0x80 means: Specifies that the point is the last point in a closed subpath (figure). so decimal 129 or 131 mean that here ends a subpath, in your case a letter (or part of a composed letter like 'i')  with either a line or a curve. You need to forward this to the svg data!!

Comment: Example: Change your loop like so: `for (int i = 0; i < a.PathPoints.Length; i++)
{
    var item = a.PathPoints[i];
    var item2 = a.PathTypes[i];
    b += " " + item.ToSvgString();
    if (item2 >= 128) b += " Z M";
}`

Comment: However, on close insepction you can see that the result is really just a fake: All curves are replaced by straight lines. So you need to test for line vs curve (ie if bit 2 is set) and if it is a curve use a bezier command!

Comment: @TaW: You should post your comments as an answer.

Comment: @TaW I used [SVG](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG) library for creating SVG.

Comment: I don't write answers here anymore. Here is a snippet that works well here: `string GP2SVG(GraphicsPath gp)
{
    string svg = "";

    int i = -1;
    while (i < gp.PathTypes.Length - 1)
    {
        i++;
        int t = gp.PathTypes[i] & 239; // clear marker bit
                
        if (t == 0) // start figure
        {
            svg += " M " + gp.PathPoints[i].ToSvgString();
            continue;
        }
        else if (t == 1 || t == 129)
        {
            svg += " L " + gp.PathPoints[i].ToSvgString();`..

Comment: ..              `if (t == 129) svg += " Z ";

            continue;
        }
        if (t == 3 || t == 131) // bezier point
        {
            svg += " C " + gp.PathPoints[i].ToSvgString() + " ";
            svg += gp.PathPoints[++i].ToSvgString() + " ";
            svg += gp.PathPoints[++i].ToSvgString() + " ";
            if (t == 131) svg += " Z ";
            continue;
        }
    }

    return svg;
}`

Comment: When you got this working for you do feel free to write it out as an answer yourself. Ping me and I will look it over..

Comment: Let me correct my comment: `129` or `131` mean here ends a __subpath (that is a series of lines or of bezier segments)__. Only `0` will start a new __figure__, like the dot of an 'i' or the next character.. - Also note that I ignore all markers, both in the GP and the SVG paths.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment, but in the TaW comment, it's missing t == 161

else if (t == 1 || t == 129 || t == 161)